# How to stop or disable changelist "updating..." in CLion?

Tags: svn, clion, changelist

When I am opening my CLion with large SVN repository, a changelists display in the following way

[image]

and this is lasting for a long time.

Is it possible to stop and/or disable this process? And what is it at all?

Comment: What is VPN here? What source control system are you using? You can see what background processes are running by clicking a progressbar in a status bar. It will pop out a window with a list of running processes.

Comment: It was a typo, I meant `SVN`.  No progress bars for background tasks are displayed.

Comment: Then your only tool to find out what's happening is [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files) (Main menu: Help - Show log in...). If the CPU usage is high during the process, you can [report a performance bug](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235-Reporting-performance-problems).